# How can I merge two different Allure results beloging to two different stages in a Jenkins Declarative Pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, devops, allure

I have a Jenkins Declarative Pipeline with 2 different test stages both are configured to generate `allure-results`

I would like to merge these two `allure-reports` into a single `allure-report` and present it to the user in the Jenkins Pipeline workspace...

```
pipeline {
    agent none

    stages {
        stage('Sanity') {
            agent { label 'sanity-node' }
            steps {
                sh 'pytest -m sanity'
                stash name: 'sanity-results', includes: 'allure-results/**'
            }
        }
        stage('Regression') {
            agent { label 'regression-node' }
            steps {
                sh 'pytest -m regression'
                stash name: 'regression-results', includes: 'allure-results/**'
            }
        }
    }

    post {
        always {
            node('master') {

                dir('merged-allure-results') {
                    unstash 'sanity-results'
                    unstash 'regression-results'
                }

                allure([
                    includeProperties: false,
                    jdk: '',
                    properties: [],
                    reportBuildPolicy: 'ALWAYS',
                    results: [[path: 'merged-allure-results']]
                ])
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But some reason it doesn't seem to work! What am I doing wrong here? How can I achieve the desired outcome?

Answer (score 1):

Allure does not know about the nested directories, so you need to pass both as results. Something like this:

```java
    post {
        always {
            node('master') {

                dir('merged-allure-results') {
                    unstash 'sanity-results'
                    unstash 'regression-results'
                }

                allure([
                    includeProperties: false,
                    jdk: '',
                    properties: [],
                    reportBuildPolicy: 'ALWAYS',
                    results: [
                        [path: 'merged-allure-results'],
                        [path: 'regression-results']
                    ]
                ])
            }
        }
    }
```

Also, I would double check if those stashes are unstashed into different directories. I don't remember the structure of the results, but I doubt they could be safely merged just by copying everything in one place.

Comment: Can you elaborate what do you mean by ```just copying everything in one place```?

Comment: All the contents of `allure-results` from `sanity` stage and `regression` stage can be copied (stashed and unstashed) into `allure-results` and generate allure report against this new `allure-results` directory? @alexander-pletnev

Comment: @BijeshMohan What I mean is that I don't remember if `unstash` automatically creates a root directory that has the same name as the stash. If not, then the files that have the same name would be overwritten by the second `unstash` - and I believe it would not be something that Allure expects.

Comment: How can I create a directory in the workspace and unstash into it @alexander-pletnev

Comment: @BijeshMohan you can use `dir('directory_name') { ... }` step